# Nginx+uWSGI+Django are returning 502 when big request body and expired session

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django view that process POST request with random size(between 20 char to 30k char). This API is only available for registered users and is validated with a session header. The API works well with my test cases but I notice some 502 in the Nginx log. The error log show this line::

```
2016/12/26 19:53:15 [error] 1048#0: *72 sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: , request: "POST /api/v1/purchase HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///opt/project/sockets/uwsgi.sock:", host: "staging.example.com"
```

After some tests, I managed to recreate this call with a big body request.

```
curl -XPOST https://staging.example.com/api/v1/purchase \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "token: development-token" \
-H "session: bad-session" \
-i -d '{"receipt-data": "<25677 character string>"}'
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 26 Dec 2016 19:54:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 181
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What it seems to happen is that the Django checks that the session is not valid and return the response(403) before the client finish delivers the body.

If I'm correct, is there a way to make Django send that 100 status after checking the headers instead of the Nginx?

If not, is there a more elegant solution than wait for the body before checking the headers?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [statement](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/issues/29#issuecomment-152941078) that adding HTTP header `connection:keep-alive` to the client should fix this issue. I'll verify it later, but already posting it here, hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have time to verify this. If you or someone could verify this, it would be great.